# Is there a not documented instruction for Typo3 LMS/flogin plugin

Tags: plugins, typo3

### Need a Login System on my Page but with integrated security Features ( like bruteforce login restriction)

downloaded this https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/flogin/
via composer on a freshly empty typo3 10.4.12 installation.

It appears in the Backend

[image: Backend]

I followed the documentation ->
https://docs.typo3.org/p/lms/login/9.0/en-us/Introduction/About/Index.html

Included the Static Typoscript in my Home / Root template

[image: BE view]

There lies the problem. The tutorial states add login form on expected page
->Tutorial Screenshot
[image: Tutorial Screenshot]

But i checked everywhere but cant find that Login Form Element
[image: Plugin Empty]
[image: Search]

Any Idea what iam missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer directly from the Developer of this Extension
Thanks again very much!

[image: answer]